# concept of index access

Tags: sql, oracle11g

> I am very new to Oracle exploring things,reading about how index access ,i got to come to a conclusion that ,suppose i have a table emp.

```
table emp
---------------------------
empno  ename  salary mgrid
---------------------------
1   ab  200 2
2   bn  900 3   
3   bh  900 1
4   ah  890 4   
5   kk  67  0   
6   ac  9090
```

> and this is how unique index on primary key empno is created

```
    index table(suppose)
--------------------
rowid  index value  
---------------------
xyzz       1
-          2
-          3
-          4
-          5
-          6
```

> where '-' means some hex value ,suppose i write a query that

```
 select * from emp where empno ='5'
```

> then it will take out the rowid corresponds to index value 5 and fetch the row corresponds to 5 empno from emp table
>
> Now my doubt is that here it is fetching from index_table ,but to find rowid it is also scanning the whole table (index_table) till 5 ,and the same usses rowid to find the row,then how it is different from the table without index?,there also we are scanning the whole table till 5 empno.
>
> only advantage is index are stored in ascending order.
>
> i know i am wrong ,but can someone explain this

```
**Doubt**
```

> Does a full table scan ,scans each and every rows column irrespective of it filter condition ?
> lets take the query that i used above ,if there is no primary key on that table emp,then it will do full table scan ,then for empno=5 ,will it scan each and every row empno value or it will scan empname,salary and mrgid also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle (or any other database) is *not* scanning the entire index in the example you posted. And that's the difference between a *heap table* and an index.

In *very* broad terms, you can compare an index with a phone book. If you want to find the phone number (the *rowid*) of *Frank Miller* in *Georgetown* (empno=5) you take the phone book and find the entries for *Georgetown*. You don't have to read the entire phone book because you know the towns are ordered. So you open the phonebook in the middle and discover the town is *Montana City*. Since Montana City comes after Georgetown you open the phone book between your current opening and the beginning. With this tactic you go on until you find Georgetown. Then you do the same thing with the last name and the first name.

Again, this works because towns, last names and first names are alphabetically ordered. In the database, this is ensured with b-trees.

You probably want to read up on b-trees for further information, for example
[on tahiti](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/indexiot.htm#CNCPT1170)

**Edit**: You also asked if the database has to scan the entire table if there is no primary key. The answer is: yes, it has to *if* there is no index on empno, either.

In the phone book analogy, this would be a query like *find all phone numbers whose address is 22 Elm Street*. Since the phone book is not ordered by street name or house number, you have to read each entry in order to find the respective phone numbers.

Comment: Thanks Rene for wonderful explaination,but can you clear one more doubt mentioned in the question posted above ,i have recently updated that

Answer (score 0):

For an index table, you can use it on more than just the primary key. For any other column, the data may not be ordered as nicely, say for "salary" in the example you provided.

In a case like this, it would be useful to use the index table, especially when you have thousands of entries.

Comment: one question,does full table scan ,scans row with specific column value or it will scan the whole row  columns values irrespective of what filter we are using,suppose i have written a query select * from emp where empno=3,here it will scan a particular row with only empno or all columns like ename,salary,mgrid?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I would assume that would consult the index table(s) of the values you are filtering.

Answer (score 0):

A "normal" index in Oracle (and in other RDBMS's) is a [B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) structure.  And golly, if only the [Oracle product documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/schema.htm#CHDJGADJ) mentioned that!